# Join tables in SQL Server and report missing data from primary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, database-design

I have 4 tables and I want to group all the data not present in the master table.

For example I have below 4 tables:

Table_A – 3000 rows:

[image]

Table_B – 200 rows:

[image]

Table_C – 150 rows:

[image]

Table_D – 800 rows:

[image]

I would like to see all the users not present in Table_A and combine them into one table (example as shown below):

[image]

I have this query, but I don’t get the desired results as above. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table_B B ON A.Phone_Number = B.Phone_Number
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table_C C ON A.Phone_Number = C.Phone_Number
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table_C D ON A.Phone_Number = D.Phone_Number
WHERE A.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would be much easier to read.

Comment: i tried, but the stakeoverflow kept on removing the table structure and just displayed values (apologies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to match on phone numbers.  If so:

```
select phone_number, max(b_name), max(c_name), max(d_name)
from ((select b.phone_number, b.employee_name as b_name, null as c_name, null as d_name
       from b 
      ) union all
      (select c.phone_number, null, c.employee_name as b_name, null as d_name
       from c 
      ) union all
      (select b.phone_number, null, null, b.employee_name as b_name
       from d
      )
     ) bcd
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.phone_number = bcd.phone_number)
group by phone_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. I can see how you would get more knowledge having the data displeyed horizontally, and it makes it hard to use later:

```
Select * from 
(
  select [Employee Name], Phone_Number From table_B
  union
  select [Employee Name], Phone_Number From table_C
  union
  select [Employee Name], Phone_Number From table_D

)
 T
where not exists
(select 1 from Table_A a where a.Phone_Number  = T.Phone_Number )
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but I would like to display them horizontally so as to figure out which table is having missing data and which tables have data. The request came from business folks

Comment: Its corrected, I had an extra union. Can you run again